# Allowing parent to process mouse event if event was not consumed by child

Tags: java, events, swing, parent-child

I have this frame:

[image]

Here is what happens:

1. When I'm over the **Pinkish** panel, the scroll pane works just fine.
2. When I put the mouse over the **Darker gray** *JTextArea* the scroll pane does not get the event.

In general my question is how can I make sure the parent of a component receives the event if the component didn't handle that specific event, even if the component has a listener and is enabled?

Perhaps a specific example will do.

You can see the calculator, the calculator is drawn on a scalable image panel, and can zoom in and out by the Ctrl + Wheel event, but when I don't press Ctrl, I would like the scroll pane to receive the event and scroll the view port. (I think this sums it)

Adam.

Comment: I could grab the JScrollPane listeners and add these to each panel, but I'm looking for a more generalized proper solution, and not to make a mess in the hierarchy of the components and listeners that would work in one case only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I described in my comment, and it works fine...

Answer (score 1):

While not entirely "neat", my [answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445297/detecting-mouse-enter-exit-events-anywhere-on-jpanel/2445786#2445786) might be adapted to do what you want to do.

Instead of a `MOUSE_EVENT_MASK` you'd use a `AWTEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL_EVENT_MASK`, and pass the event to the scrollpane when the control key state is appropriate.

(With any luck someone will post a "real" mechanism to forward an event to the parent component).

Comment: No exactly what I had in mind, I'll see how I do this... Thanks for the Idea.