# Detect mouse click anywhere on window

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, windowlistener

I've written a JWindow that acts a bit like a fancy menu in my application, popping up when a button is pressed. However, I'd like it to disappear if the user clicks anywhere in the main window. I can of course add a mouse listener to the main window, but that doesn't add it to all the components on the window itself, and looping over all the components seems like a bit of a brute force solution (and can't be guaranteed to work if the components on the window change.)

What's the best way of going about doing something like this?

Comment: Please see this post [Detecting mouse enter/exit events anywhere on JPanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445297/detecting-mouse-enter-exit-events-anywhere-on-jpanel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(listener, eventMask)`. Find eventMask that filters only mouse clicks. This AWT listener is global for whole application, so you can see all events that happen.

Comment: +1 just beware: that might not work in security restricted environments

Comment: @kleopatra, you are absolutely right (+1). The permissions are checked in `addAWTEventListener()`. So, this is the limitation.

Answer (score 3):

> I'd like it to disappear if the user clicks anywhere in the main window

Add a `WindowListener` to the child window and then handle the `windowDeactiveated()` event and invoke setVisible(false) on the child window.

Working example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DialogDeactivated
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final WindowListener wl = new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e)
            {
                e.getWindow().setVisible(false);
            }
        };

        JButton button = new JButton("Show Popup");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
                JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(button);

                JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, false);
                dialog.setUndecorated(true);
                dialog.add( new JButton("Dummy Button") );
                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setLocationRelativeTo( frame );
                dialog.setVisible( true );
                dialog.addWindowListener( wl );
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
     }
}
```

Comment: I initially tried this because it seemed like the simplest way to go, however I the `windowDeactiveated()` event never seemed to register which seemed a bit odd. It worked fine with a `JFrame`, but as soon as I switched to `JWindow`. Don't suppose you've any idea why this happened? I've done it the other way now but I'm intriguied :)

Comment: @berry120, not sure, but you can try using an undecorated JDialog instead of a JWindow. Or if as your question states you are using a fancy menu, then why not just use t JPopupMenu and you get this behaviour by default?

Comment: it's not exactly like a menu, there's various aspects such as when you click an item it goes away that I don't really want - more like a cross between a menu and a dialog! Difficult to explain but it works well in the context I'm using it in. Did try using an undecorated JDialog but it didn't work either. Ah well, I guess I'll just stick with the awtevent approach. Thanks for the insight though, this would have been a cleaner solution if it'd worked!

Comment: @berry120, it works fine for me. Do you actually have a focusable component on the dialog? See edit for a SSCCE.

Comment: Damn - I feel silly now. No, I didn't have a focusable component there at all - thanks very much for the example. Makes perfect sense now!