# GUI testing library with user actions recording?

Tags: java, junit, mouse, awtrobot, fest

I want to make junit test for an application, with graphics editor like functionality. I.e. user can drag and drop mouse smoothly in GUI. It seems not usefull to write coordinate movements programmatically. Is it possible to have some macro recording, to capture user guestures and then use them for testing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use AWTEventListener to accomplish this task.

possilbly duplicate of [Detecting mouse enter/exit events anywhere on JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445297/detecting-mouse-enter-exit-events-anywhere-on-jpanel)

Or you can refer to [java2.com example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Event/voidjavaawtToolkitaddAWTEventListenerAWTEventListenerlistenerlongeventMask.htm).