# how to fire MouseListener event methods if it's already running

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

**In my code i Have:**

A JFrame with a normal JPanel which contains some JComponent Object.
These JComponents has: 
- a list of JTextFields.
- a listener which highlight its border when mouseEntered fires, and hide it when mouseExited fires.
Since the mouseExited method fires also when the cursor goes over a jtextField nested into the JComponent, the implementetion of the mouseExited method check if the cursor location of the event is outside the JComponentArea before hiding the border:

**The problem is:**

If you move the mouse slowly, the code seems to works fine, but if you move it fast between components, sometimes the Border of a JComponent is not hidden.
I thought it could be because the mouseExited is fired when the cursor goes over a nested textField and then again when cursor is outside  the JComponent, but i m not sure what s the real problem.
Thanks in advance for any hint or help!!

**The Code:**

Code has been written on purpose of the problem described above. here is the Jcomponent class (MyContainer) and the class including the Main (MyClass):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {       
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){   
                int i=0;
                //mainWindow
                    JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("MyFrame");
                    mainWindow.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    mainWindow.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300,300));

                    JPanel viewPort = new JPanel();
                    viewPort.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

                    MyContainer one = new MyContainer();
                    MyContainer two = new MyContainer();
                    MyContainer three = new MyContainer();

                    viewPort.add(one);
                    viewPort.add(two);
                    viewPort.add(three);
                    mainWindow.add(viewPort,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    mainWindow.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}





import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public  class MyContainer extends JComponent {
            JTextField text1 ;
            JTextField text2 ;
            JTextField text3 ;

            public MyContainer(){
                super.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
                super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,50));
                super.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
                super.setBackground(Color.green);

                text1 = new JTextField("LABEL_1");
                text1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60,30));
                text1.setEditable(false);
                this.add(text1);

                text2 = new JTextField("LABEL_2");
                text2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60,30));
                text2.setEditable(false);
                this.add(text2);

                text3 = new JTextField("LABEL_3");
                text3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60,30));
                text3.setEditable(false);
                this.add(text3);

                addListener();
            }

            private void addListener() {
                this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                        MyContainer.this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                        Rectangle r = e.getComponent().getBounds();
                        Point p = e.getPoint();
                        if( p.x < 0 || p.y < 0 || p.x >= r.width || p.y >= r.height)
                            MyContainer.this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
                    }

                    @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { /*NOTHING*/ }
                    @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { /*NOTHING*/ }
                    @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { /*NOTHING*/ }
                });         
            }
        }
```

Comment: [These](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445297/detecting-mouse-enter-exit-events-anywhere-on-jpanel) answers may be useful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible implementation using `MyContainer.this.dispatchEvent(SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(JTextField, e, MyContainer.this));`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyClass2 {
  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        //mainWindow
        JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("MyFrame");
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainWindow.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

        JPanel viewPort = new JPanel();
        viewPort.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        MyContainer one = new MyContainer();
        MyContainer two = new MyContainer(true);
        viewPort.add(makeTitledPanel(one, "move it fast: NG?"));
        viewPort.add(makeTitledPanel(two, "move it fast: OK?"));
        mainWindow.add(viewPort, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }
  private static JComponent makeTitledPanel(JComponent c, String title) {
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
    p.add(c);
    return p;
  }
}

class MyContainer extends JComponent {
  JTextField text1 ;
  JTextField text2 ;
  JTextField text3 ;
  private final boolean flag;
  public MyContainer() {
    this(false);
  }
  public MyContainer(boolean flag) {
    super();
    this.flag = flag;

    super.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
    super.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
    super.setBackground(Color.green);

    text1 = new JTextField("LABEL_1");
    text2 = new JTextField("LABEL_2");
    text3 = new JTextField("LABEL_3");

    MouseListener l = new MouseEventConverter();
    for (JTextField f : Arrays.asList(text1, text2, text3)) {
      f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 30));
      f.setEditable(false);
      if (flag) {
        f.addMouseListener(l);
      }
      this.add(f);
    }
    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        MyContainer.this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
      }
      @Override
      public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        Rectangle r = e.getComponent().getBounds();
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        if (p.x < 0 || p.y < 0 || p.x >= r.width || p.y >= r.height) {
          MyContainer.this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

class MouseEventConverter extends MouseAdapter {
  @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    dispatchMouseEvent(e);
  }
  @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    dispatchMouseEvent(e);
  }
  private void dispatchMouseEvent(MouseEvent e) {
    Component c = e.getComponent();
    Component p = SwingUtilities.getUnwrappedParent(c);
    p.dispatchEvent(SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(c, e, p));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using static methods, though I'm unsure of any actual impact of doing it your way. I'd recommend

```
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    ((MyContainer) e.getSource()).setBorder(...)
}

// and so forth
```

Additionally, the issue is probably with your `mouseExited` method. Instead of using `.getBounds()` I recommend using `instanceof`

```
if(e.getSource() instanceof MyContainer) {
    // do the stuff
} else {
    // do nothing
}
```

Alternatively:

```
if(!(e.getSource() instanceof JTextField)) {
    // do the stuff
} else {
    // do nothing
}
```

The `else` statement isn't even necessary; I'm just including it for completeness.

Comment: I think the problem is the mouseExited method too, since it's the one charged to hide the border.
By the way the listener is given to the container, not to it's nested JTextField, so when the mouse is moved from any nested JTextField to outSide the container too fast, it doesn't fire :(

Comment: In that case you'd need to do more heavy lifting; placing a `MouseListener` on the `JTextField` as well. When exiting the field, `if instanceof MyContainer do nothing`, and `else remove border` (as we assume you've gone straight from the `JTextField` to the outside.

Comment: it could works, but i should check if it is the jTextField container object, otherwise it could not hide it if i move to another container, am i right?

Comment: Well it looks like you've found an answer already, but you don't always need to check for it being a `JTextField`, if it isn't `MyContainer` then it will always be `JTextField` according to your code :)