# Java: define unit component for mouse events

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, components, mouseevent

I want to have a `JPanel` called `mainPanel` and add several components on it; Also I defined a `mouseAdapter` and added to my `mainPanel` that overrides `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` to for example change background color of `mainPanel` when mouse entered it. But when mouse entered to `mainPanel` and entered to components I added on it (for example labels) `mouseExited` event is called; But I don't want this as mouse is in area of `mainPanel`; I want it be called just when mouse exited `mainPanel` area; and also want this for `mouseEntered`. I previously added `mouseListeners` to components on `mainPanel` but it is not a clear solution. Can anyone tell me a clear way for my purpose?

thanks your attention; 
Good lock

Comment: Maybe a code example will help.

Comment: Start [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).

Comment: See the answer to [this][1] question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882055/java-swing-change-background-color-on-mouse-over

Answer (score 2):

You want the `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` to be called on full boundaries. This is, as you have noticed, not directly possible with the "normal" `MouseListener`.

The simplest way is to add the listener to all child-components of the panel:

```
private static void addListenerToAllComponents(JComponent c, MouseListener l) {

    c.addMouseListener(l);

    for (Component cc : c.getComponents())
        if (cc instanceof JComponent)
            addListenerToAllComponents((JComponent) cc, l);
}
```

**Full example:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    frame.add(new JLabel("Testing"), BorderLayout.NORTH);

    final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    panel.setBackground(Color.RED);

    MouseListener l = new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        }
    };

    panel.add(new JLabel("Hello"));
    panel.add(new JTextField("World!"));

    addListenerToAllComponents(panel, l);

    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

---

### Another workaround (previous answer)...

...is to set a [GlassPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#glasspane) and check bounds yourself:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    frame.add(new JLabel("Testing"), BorderLayout.NORTH);

    final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    panel.add(new JLabel("Hello"));
    panel.add(new JTextField("World!"));

    class GlassPane extends JComponent {
        GlassPane(final JComponent c) {
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

                    Point p = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(e.getComponent(), 
                                                          e.getPoint(), 
                                                          c);

                    if (c.contains(p))
                        c.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                    else
                        c.setBackground(Color.RED);
                }
            });

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    c.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
                }
            });
        }
    }        

    GlassPane glass = new GlassPane(panel);
    frame.setGlassPane(glass);
    glass.setVisible(true);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

---

There are some stuff you need to look in to... Event redistribution is one and might be a problem in your case. Follow [this example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/GlassPaneDemoProject/src/components/GlassPaneDemo.java) and implement an event distribution listener on the glass pane:

```
MouseInputListener i = new MouseInputListener() {

    private void redispatchMouseEvent(MouseEvent e) {

        Point glassPanePoint = e.getPoint();
        Container container = frame.getContentPane();

        Point containerPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(
                GlassPane.this,
                glassPanePoint,
                container);

        Component component = 
            SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt(
                    container,
                    containerPoint.x,
                    containerPoint.y);

        if (component != null) {

            Point componentPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(
                    GlassPane.this,
                    glassPanePoint,
                    component);

            component.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(component,
                    e.getID(),
                    e.getWhen(),
                    e.getModifiers(),
                    componentPoint.x,
                    componentPoint.y,
                    e.getClickCount(),
                    e.isPopupTrigger()));
        }
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        redispatchMouseEvent(e);
    }
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        redispatchMouseEvent(e);
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        redispatchMouseEvent(e);
    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        redispatchMouseEvent(e);
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        redispatchMouseEvent(e);
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        redispatchMouseEvent(e);
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        redispatchMouseEvent(e);
    }
};

addMouseListener(i);
addMouseMotionListener(i);
```

Comment: Thank you. I saw the demo and yes it works. But it is so complicated and special example. I am looking for a simple way.

Comment: @sajad: Added nother example (first) where I add the same listener for all child-components. Is it simple enough?

Answer (score 2):

Getting mouseEvents for a component and all its children is ... tricky to get right. You might consider to rely on stable (and extensively tested :-) code around. The jdk7 way of doing it is to use a JLayer (which internally registers an AWTEventListener as it has all priviledges). For earlier versions, you can use its predecessor [JXLayer](http://java.net/downloads/jxlayer/)